Gazebo Fortress crashing on Raspberry Pi
I've recently installed Gazebo Fortress for ROS2 Humble in Ubuntu 22.04, on a Raspberry Pi 4B with 4GB RAM. I have replaced the Ogre2 renderer for Ogre, as OpenGL 3.3 isn't available on this device. However, when the window opens, the render is just a black screen, and I have to place a shape for it to actually load anything. that is, if placing the shape doesn't cause it to crash in the first place. When running it with a robot model, it mysteriously crashes outputting this message:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread 2949: 
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#18 Object "[0xffffffffffffffff]", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#17 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffff9ece5edb, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#16 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffff9ec7d5c7, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#15 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffff973722db, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#14 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff9852e6c3, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#13 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff9852dfc7, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#12 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff9858e093, in QQuickWindowPrivate::renderSceneGraph(QSize const&, QSize const&) [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#11 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff9851ec43, in QSGDefaultRenderContext::renderNextFrame(QSGRenderer*, unsigned int) [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#10 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff984bcb0f, in QSGRenderer::renderScene(unsigned int) [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#9 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff984bc66f, in QSGRenderer::renderScene(QSGBindable const&) [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#8 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff984d4033, in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::render() [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#7 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff984d3877, in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderBatches() [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#6 Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffff984ced17, in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderMergedBatch(QSGBatchRenderer::Batch const*) [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#5 Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/vc4_dri.so", at 0xffff803fe2e7, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#4 Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/vc4_dri.so", at 0xffff803fc8d3, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#3 Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/vc4_dri.so", at 0xffff80ffccbf, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#2 Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/vc4_dri.so", at 0xffff80fef16f, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#1 Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/vc4_dri.so", at 0xffff80ff318f, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
#0 Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/vc4_dri.so", at 0xffff80fe84d0, in [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] 
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [0x10]) 
[INFO] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 2862] 
[INFO] [launch]: process[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] was required: shutting down launched system 
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[robot_state_publisher-1] [robot_state_publisher-1] 
[INFO] [1719511158.821937034] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2).

Other times, it just causes my entire Raspberry Pi to freeze! In one of these times, my screen turned black and then this message started to appear on screen, as time went by:
[605.159693] INFO: task Xorg:1282 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[605.159773]       Tainted: G         C  E     5.15.0-1055-raspi #58-Ubuntu
[605.159811] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix my Gazebo?
Also, my teleop_twist_keyboard doesn't seem to be working, not sure if that might be related.
